# Error when use tabIndex in Autocomplete of MUI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, tabindex

I want to use `tabIndex` in autocomplete of MUI using `inputProps={{ tabIndex: tabIndex ?? -1 }}` but when I use this property , and then clicked on dropdown button page disappear can any body help me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to spread the `params.inputProps` from the `Autocomplete`:

```
<TextField
  {...params}
  inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, tabIndex: 1 }}
  label="freeSolo"
/>
```

Comment: yessssssssssssss , that's right , thanks very much